# Task.Run then Invoke on main thread alternative using async await ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

The following code works perfectly.  It shows the spinner on the UI, starts a task using a thread from the threadpool and runs the heavy operation, once complete, logic to hide the spinner executes on the main thread as intended.

```
    public void LoadCustomers()
    {
        // Update UI to show spinner
        this.LoadingCustomers = true;

        Task.Run(async () =>            
        {
            var customers = await this.custService.GetCustomers();
            // code truncated for clarity

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
            {
                // Update UI to hide spinner
                this.LoadingCustomers = false;
            });
        });
    }
```

My question; Is there a better way to write this logic using ContinueWith/ConfigureAwait options? Using these options seems to block the UI thread. In the example below, shouldn't the UI thread continue running the UI logic (animating the spinner/user input) and then come back to complete the logic inside the ContinueWith?

```
    public void LoadCustomers()
    {
        // Update UI to show spinner
        this.LoadingCustomers = true;

        this.custService.GetCustomers().ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            var customers = t.Result;
            // code truncated for clarity

            // Update UI to hide spinner
            this.LoadingCustomers = false;
        });
    }
```

As requested in the comments, here is the code for GetCustomers. the dbContext is EntityFrameworkCore.

```
    public async Task<List<CustomerModel>> GetCustomers()
    {
        return await this.dbContext.Customers.ToListAsync();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The answer by FCin is correct, however; the cause root of this seems to be with EFCore and ToListAsync, it isn't running asynchronously.

Comment: How is `GetCustomers` implemented? It might be blocking before it returns a `Task`. You can also make `LoadCustomers` be `async Task` and thus avoid having to explicitly use `ContinueWith` (or `async void` if you need it as a handler of a specific type)

Comment: What framework? Asp.net? wpf? winforms?

Comment: I've updated the question with the GetCustomers method, and it is a Xamarin Forms project

Comment: If `GetCustomers` is already an `async` supporting `Task`, why bother using `Task.Run`, instead of just awaiting it directly?  The compiler will automatically convert your `async` methods in to a series of continuations behind the scenes.  This is exactly what `async` / `await` was designed for.

Comment: [...]Unless there is something in the `// code truncated for clarity` that requires a different thread.  If it's just "normal" code, I would strongly recommend directly awaiting; you won't have to worry about marshaling across threads at all.

Answer (score 8):

Proper way of writing such method is to use `async/await` from start to finish. Right now you are doing fire and forget meaning if there is exception inside `Task.Run` you will never know about it. You should start from an event handler. This can be whatever, mouse click, page loaded, etc.

```
private async void MouseEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await LoadCustomers();
}

public async Task LoadCustomers()
{
    // Update UI to show spinner
    this.LoadingCustomers = true;

    // We don't need Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, because await automatically 
    // goes back to calling thread when it is finished
    var customers = await this.custService.GetCustomers();

    this.LoadingCustomers = false;
}
```

There is an easy way to remember when to use `Task.Run`. Use `Task.Run` *only* when you do something CPU bound, such as calculating digits of PI.

Comment: you need to add async to event handler signature.

Comment: Note that this requires `GetCustomers` to be well-written, to not block the thread it is running on. In the question's original code, GetCustomers was running on a task thread.  No matter how it was written internally, that would not block the UI thread. In this version, GetCustomers runs on the main thread (because it is awaited while on main thread). As long as most of its work is done via an await to something non-blocking (e.g. an async i/o call), this approach is good.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: @bradley-uffner suggested to just write the following:

```
public async Task LoadCustomers()
{
    // Update UI to show spinner
    this.LoadingCustomers = true;

    var customers = await this.custService.GetCustomers();
    // code truncated for clarity

    // you are still on UI thread here
    this.LoadingCustomers = false;
}
```

---

How about this:

```
public async Task LoadCustomers()
{
    // Update UI to show spinner
    this.LoadingCustomers = true;

    await Task.Run(async () =>            
    {
        var customers = await this.custService.GetCustomers();
        // code truncated for clarity
    });

    this.LoadingCustomers = false;
}
```

The code after `await` is executed on the current thread so it should work out of the box.

Comment: If `this.custService.GetCustomers()` is already an `async` supporting `Task`, why bothing using `Task.Run`, instead of just awaiting it directly?

Comment: I actually didn't even inspect the content of the code :D Let me fix that.

Comment: Note the upvotes on first comment. Please explain the benefit of this version. I *think* it might ensure that the main thread isn't blocked, if `GetCustomers` is poorly written - if it blocks whatever thread it is on. Otherwise, this is unneeded code complexity, with no benefit. But if that is the case, then GetCustomers should be re-written to fix the problem (so that the "before" version is sufficient). REASON: GetCustomers is written as an `async Task`. That is an assertion that it won't block when called. Calling code should be able to rely on that assertion.